# Why can't I set up a variable date in my VBScript which changes incrementally

Tags: vbscript, datediff

I have a Vbscript  which outputs the time taken for my anti-virus  to update the  signature  version on a daily basis at 05:00 AM, before performing a scan. This is the script

```
    Function TimeSpan(dt1, dt2) 
    If (isDate(dt1) And IsDate(dt2)) = false Then
       TimeSpan = "00:00:00" 
        Exit Function 
    End If 

    seconds = Abs(DateDiff("S", dt1, dt2)) 
    minutes = seconds \ 60 
    hours = minutes \ 60 
    minutes = minutes mod 60 
    seconds = seconds mod 60 

    if len(hours) = 1 then hours = "0" & hours 

    TimeSpan = hours & ":" & _ 
        RIGHT("00" & minutes, 2) & ":" & _ 
        RIGHT("00" & seconds, 2) 
End Function 
d1 = LAST_UPDATE
d2 = 22 Jul 20 05:00:00AM
```

d1 [ LAST_UPDATE ] is the  time  the update is completed, so what I need is the starting time. The script runs accurately as long as I incorporate the date and time in ' d2 ' [ as shown in the script ].  This means that to output the  result on a  daily basis, I have to  open the vbscript and change the  date to current date [ the time remains constant at 05:00:00 AM ]
The output result  is  given to me after 10 minutes.
I have tried using ' Now ()'  but this output includes the time taken from the time the  update is completed and the 10 minutes [ that has lapsed ]  till the result is provided. This doesnot  serve the purpose of this script.
What I  am trying to get at is, is there a  way which  can be incorporated in the script itself,[ with another fuction or so ] which will change the  date [ to tomorrow ]  and the time [ the  time remains constant at  05:00:00 AM ] incrementally after every 24 hours at  12:00:00 AM in the script itself keepiing it ready for the  next  day's operation without  any user  action of  changing the date manually
I have  tried all ways possible to resolve this but have failed. My  efforts always  culminate  in ' Now() '   and the entire excercise  is wasted.
Any help will be  appreciated.This is the  script

Rajdeep

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to measure the time it takes for the anti-virus update to run, you can use the [Timer function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/a3fb2dtc(v=vs.84)) like this:

```
Dim sngStart
Dim sngTimeSpan

sngStart = Timer

' Do work here

sngTimeSpan = Timer - sngStart
```

`sngTimeSpan` is a value in seconds.

You can do the same with the [Now function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/0w568awd(v=vs.84)):

```
Dim dStart
dStart = Now

' Do work here

seconds = Abs(DateDiff("S", dStart, Now))
```

Essentially you are calling `Timer` or `Now` twice and calculating the difference between the two, eliminating the need for the `d2` variable.

Here's a complete example using a `MsgBox` to simulate some task being performed:

```
Dim sngStart
Dim sngEnd
Dim sngSecondsElapsed
Dim iSecondsElapsed
Dim dStart

' Grab system Timer and current time
sngStart = Timer
dStart = Now

' Simulating a delay here by displaying a message box
MsgBox "Click OK after a few moments"

' Calculate seconds elapsed
sngSecondsElapsed = Timer - sngStart
iSecondsElapsed = Abs(DateDiff("S", dStart, Now))
    
MsgBox "Seconds Elapsed:" & vbCrLf & "Timer method: " & FormatNumber(sngSecondsElapsed, 2) & vbCrLf & "Now method: " & iSecondsElapsed
```

Comment: Laneville ~ Thank you so much for the  prompt reply. I had  read about the  Timer function, but it didn't strike me that I  could somehow resolve this by using this alternative. Judging from the size of the community, I am hopeful that my query may get solved soon, for which I'll like to wait  for a day or two. In the meanwhile, I am implementing your suggestions of using the Timer function to see how this works out.